# Event not saved in Calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to save an event in the calendar directly, without openning the calendar app. I have found that in some devices the event is not saved in calendar, but I am not getting any error in the logcat. This is the code that I am using,

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues()
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, DateBuilder.getStartDayCalendar());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, DateBuilder.getEndDayCalendar());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Title");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "description");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);         
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In same devices you need to set up the status,`Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED`, that was the problem

Comment: I am getting same issue on Xioami A1. I event tried `Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED` but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the solution :

Follow the steps it will create event directly :

Manifest.xml

Add permissions in Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="testpreference.com.testcalendar.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calendars" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/calendarid_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newevent_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Event"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Date;
        import java.util.Enumeration;
        import java.util.Hashtable;
        import java.util.List;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
            private Spinner calendarIdSpinner;
            private Hashtable<String,String> calendarIdTable;
            private Button newEventButton;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                calendarIdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.calendarid_spinner);
                newEventButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newevent_button);

                newEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (CalendarHelper.haveCalendarReadWritePermissions(MainActivity.this))
                        {
                            addNewEvent();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CalendarHelper.requestCalendarReadWritePermission(MainActivity.this);
                        }
                    }
                });


                calendarIdSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

                if (CalendarHelper.haveCalendarReadWritePermissions(this))
                {
                    //Load calendars
                    calendarIdTable = CalendarHelper.listCalendarId(this);

                    updateCalendarIdSpinner();

                }


            }

            private void updateCalendarIdSpinner()
            {
                if (calendarIdTable==null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                Enumeration e = calendarIdTable.keys();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
                    list.add(key);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                calendarIdSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

                if (requestCode==CalendarHelper.CALENDARHELPER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
                {
                    if (CalendarHelper.haveCalendarReadWritePermissions(this))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, (String)"Have Calendar Read/Write Permission.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }

                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }

            private void addNewEvent()
            {
                if (calendarIdTable==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, (String)"No calendars found. Please ensure at least one google account has been added.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Load calendars
                    calendarIdTable = CalendarHelper.listCalendarId(this);

                    updateCalendarIdSpinner();

                    return;
                }


                final long oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
                final long tenMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 10;

                long oneHourFromNow = (new Date()).getTime() + oneHour;
                long tenMinutesFromNow = (new Date()).getTime() + tenMinutes;


                String calendarString = calendarIdSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                int calendar_id = Integer.parseInt(calendarIdTable.get(calendarString));

                CalendarHelper.MakeNewCalendarEntry(this, "Test", "Add event", "Somewhere",tenMinutesFromNow,tenMinutesFromNow+oneHour,false,true,calendar_id,3);

            }

        }
```

2. Create class for calendar selection

   ```
    import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

       private static final String TAG = "OnItemSelectedListener";

       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
           Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                   "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Log.v(TAG,"onNohingSelected() called.");
       }

   }
   ```
3. CalendarHelper.java

   ```
   import android.Manifest;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.ContentResolver;
   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
   import android.provider.CalendarContract.Reminders;
   import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
   import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
   import android.util.Log;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Hashtable;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.TimeZone;

   public class CalendarHelper {

       //Remember to initialize this activityObj first, by calling initActivityObj(this) from
   //your activity
       private static final String TAG = "CalendarHelper";
       public static final int CALENDARHELPER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 99;


       public static void MakeNewCalendarEntry(Activity caller,String title,String description,String location,long startTime,long endTime, boolean allDay,boolean hasAlarm, int calendarId,int selectedReminderValue) {

           ContentResolver cr = caller.getContentResolver();
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(Events.DTSTART, startTime);
           values.put(Events.DTEND, endTime);
           values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
           values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
           values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
           values.put(Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);


           if (allDay)
           {
               values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, true);
           }

           if (hasAlarm)
           {
               values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
           }

           //Get current timezone
           values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
           Log.i(TAG, "Timezone retrieved=>"+TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
           Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
           Log.i(TAG, "Uri returned=>"+uri.toString());
           // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
           long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

           if (hasAlarm)
           {
               ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
               reminders.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
               reminders.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
               reminders.put(Reminders.MINUTES, selectedReminderValue);

               Uri uri2 = cr.insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);
           }


       }

       public static void requestCalendarReadWritePermission(Activity caller)
       {
           List<String> permissionList = new ArrayList<String>();

           if  (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(caller,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
           {
               permissionList.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);

           }

           if  (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(caller,Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
           {
               permissionList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);

           }

           if (permissionList.size()>0)
           {
               String [] permissionArray = new String[permissionList.size()];

               for (int i=0;i<permissionList.size();i++)
               {
                   permissionArray[i] = permissionList.get(i);
               }

               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(caller,
                       permissionArray,
                       CALENDARHELPER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
           }

       }

       public static Hashtable listCalendarId(Context c) {

           if (haveCalendarReadWritePermissions((Activity)c)) {

               String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
               Uri calendars;
               calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

               ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
               Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);

               if (managedCursor.moveToFirst())
               {
                   String calName;
                   String calID;
                   int cont = 0;
                   int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
                   int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                   Hashtable<String,String> calendarIdTable = new Hashtable<>();

                   do
                   {
                       calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
                       calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
                       Log.v(TAG, "CalendarName:" + calName + " ,id:" + calID);
                       calendarIdTable.put(calName,calID);
                       cont++;
                   } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
                   managedCursor.close();

                   return calendarIdTable;
               }

           }

           return null;

       }

       public static boolean haveCalendarReadWritePermissions(Activity caller)
       {
           int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(caller,
                   Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);

           if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
           {
               permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(caller,
                       Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);

               if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }

           return false;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could your be more concise about the problem that I am facing? I have checked also for permission before writing the event to calendar, that is not the problem. The only thing I see that differs from my code is that I haven't set an EVENT_STATUS

Comment: see create and example this you will get whats going problem

Comment: Don't see only insert method before inserting you have to select specific calendar. that is the problem. I have done recently so i shared you full code.

Comment: I will check it, I thought I could pass calendar_id as 1 to take the default calendar

Comment: No, Not 1. create example and debug you will get.

Comment: I have checked the log and what I get when I list the calendars is: "My Calendar", id = 1 and "email@gmail.com", id =2. If I use as calendar_id 1 or 2, the event is not being written in any case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142706/discussion-between-rajasekhar-and-spirrow).

Comment: I am getting same issue on Xioami A1. I event tried `Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED` but still getting same issue.