# Adding Event to Outlook Calendar

Tags: android, events, outlook, calendar

Below is my code to Add calendar Account and then adding Event to that calendar,

```
AuthenticationManager.getInstance().setContextActivity(this);

    AuthenticationManager.getInstance().connect(
            new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectButtonClick - Successfully connected to Office 365");
                    String type = result.getUserInfo().getIdentityProvider();
                    String accountOwner = result.getUserInfo().getDisplayableId();
                    addCalendar(type, accountOwner);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(final Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate - " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Calendar Method:

```
 public void addCalendar(String type, String accountOwner) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountOwner);
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, type);
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, accountOwner);
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "Outlook");
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, "232323");
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR);
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, accountOwner);
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "METHOD_ALERT, METHOD_EMAIL, METHOD_ALARM");
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_ATTENDEE_TYPES, "TYPE_OPTIONAL, TYPE_REQUIRED, TYPE_RESOURCE");
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_AVAILABILITY, "AVAILABILITY_BUSY, AVAILABILITY_FREE, AVAILABILITY_TENTATIVE");


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, 23);
    }

    Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountOwner)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, type).build();
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, contentValues);
}
```

Adding Event:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Tech Stores");
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Successful Startups");
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 10);
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "London");
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, "1");
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_SEE_GUESTS, "1");
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER, "azhar@outlook.com");

                    cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The problem is, the event is not getting added to the desired Calendar. I'm not getting any error too. Any correction needed here?

Answer (score 1):

You could add “ CALENDAR_ID ”  parameter to the Events, For example:

values.put(CalendarContract.Events. CALENDAR_ID, “”);

For more information, please refer to this link:

[CalendarContract.Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events)

Comment: Have you checked this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776265/android-create-calendar-event-always-as-birthday    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215180/what-should-be-calendar-id-while-adding-event-to-calendar-in-android

Comment: yes, i'm adding proper Calendar ID to which I want to add

Comment: @Azhar Bandri   Maybe this link will help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628629/event-not-saved-in-calendar

Comment: Added CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED. Still not working

Comment: @Azhar Bandri  Do you check based on the step of link's answer

Comment: Yes, I have added the Status Parameter as mentioned in that link